# iOS ParseError : Attempted to change an objectId to one that's already known to the Offline Store

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm having a regular issue with my project, using Parse Server. First, I call a Parse Cloud function to populate a user's data list :

```
var dataSet: Set<MyData>?

func loadData(withParameters parameters: [String : Any]) {

        PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "loadData", withParameters: parameters) { (success, error) in

            if let objects = success as? [[String : Any]] {

                let dataTable: [MyData] = objects.map({ (object) -> MyData in

                    let myData = MyData(dataSource: PFObject(className: "MyData", 
                                        dictionary: object))
                    myData.dataSource?.objectId = object["objectId"] as? String
                    return myData
                })

                if self.dataSet == nil {
                    self.dataSet = []
                }

                self.dataSet = Set(dataTable)
            }
        }
    }
```

On the code mentioned above, I have to set the `objectId` because without this, no matter how many objects I fetch from Parse, when I reduce the array to a set with the last instruction I end up with only one object in it.

However, although this works, when I call this function again to update user's data, I get this error on the `myData.dataSource?.objectId = temp["objectId"] as? String` line :

> Attempted to change an objectId to one that's already known to the Offline Store.

Tried to find some information about it but nothing very relevant...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no really an answer, but too long for a comment:

I understand the following:
Your cloud function `loadData` returns `success`, which is an array of dictionaries or, probably in case of an error, `nil`. If `nil` is returned, you do nothing.
If an array is returned, it is referred as `objects`.
This array is then mapped to an array of elements of type `MyData`.
For every element returned from the cloud function, called `object`, a `MyData` instance is created using as `dataSource` **a new** `PFObject` instance of class `MyData` and properties given by the object dictionary.
I do not understand the next statement by which you assign the `objectId` of the object returned from the cloud function to the newly created `PFObject`: As far as I know, `objectIds` must be unique, and cannot (or at least should not) be assigned to other `PFObjects`.
But you said you have to do this or otherwise you end up with a single element in the resulting set (see below).
Anyway, you have now an array of `MyData` instances in `dataTable`.
Then, you initialise `dataSet`, which is not required since it will be overwritten anyway by your last statement.
This statement makes a set of the `dataTable` array.

Now, when you get a single element in this set in case you do not set the `objectId` property of the elements of the `dataTable` array, this means that all elements of this array are the same object.  And this means that your init function

```
MyData(dataSource: PFObject(className: "MyData", 
                                        dictionary: object))
```

returns always the same object, and this object is made to a different one by setting its `objectId` property. This is very strange to me. Please check what it going on there.

Now if you call `loadData` once more to update the data, the cloud function probably returns some or all of the previous objects again. In this case, you would assign an old `objectId`, that has already been assigned earlier to a `PFObject` created in the map function, to another newly created `PFObject` created there, which is not allowed, thus the error message.

To cut it short:
If the same object is returned from the cloud function repeatedly, you must not create different `PFObjects` for them, and assign them the same `objectId`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for coming back so late, I think I got it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Protocols/PFSubclassing.html

> If a subclass of PFObject conforms to PFSubclassing and calls PFObject.+registerSubclass, Parse framework will be able to use that class as the native class for a Parse cloud object.

For example:

1.Create your subclass of PFObject

```
import Parse

class Question: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    @NSManaged var category: String?
    @NSManaged var text: String
    @NSManaged var image: PFFile?
    @NSManaged var answerType: String
    @NSManaged var order: NSNumber

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Question"
    }
}

class User: PFUser {

    @NSManaged var fullname: String
}
```

2.Register subclass

```
extension Parse {
    class func registerSubclasses() {
        User.registerSubclass()
        Question.registerSubclass()
    }
}
```

3.Configure parse service once app launches

```
Parse.registerSubclasses()
Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
Parse.setApplicationId(PARSE_APP_ID, clientKey: PARSE_APP_KEY)
```

4.Now `PFUser == User`, `Question == PFObject(className: "Question")`

5.It works for Cloud Function

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("fetchQuestions", withParameters: parameters) { questions, error in
            if let questions = questions as? [Question] {
                completion?(questions, nil)
            } else {
                completion?(nil, error)
            }
        }
```

Note: the swift code may be old, there should be some changes if using higher swift version.